# Getting SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while using site deployed on Netlify/Render

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, mongodb, express

I have built a Full-stack MERN (React + Node.js + MongoDB) application by following this YouTube tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FcxjCPeicvU

After ensuring both frontend and backend apps were working properly on my local machine, I decided to deploy them online. For deploying both frontend and backend, I used [Render](https://render.com/).

I first deployed the backend to Render, and when I tried to connect my **local** frontend app with the **deployed** backend app, it worked great. I could perform actions like **Sign up**/**Log in** without any issues.

[image: Login working in local frontend]

Then I deployed my frontend app on Render as well (here's the web app - https://notes-app-xjr0.onrender.com). When I clicked on the above URL, it landed on the Application home page without any issue. Now here comes the interesting part.

When I tried to log in to my account (user account was already present in MongoDB), I get the error - `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`. I'm getting the same error when trying to sign up with the app.

[image: Error while logging in]

This is very puzzling, as the app was working fine when I tried to connect my **local** frontend app with the **deployed** backend app. To check if the API is misbehaving in any way, I tried to call the APIs from **Postman** as well - and received the correct responses each time for all API endpoints.

I tried to deploy the **frontend** app to [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) as well (https://notes-app-01.netlify.app), but I am getting the same error.

Can anyone please help me figure out the issue?

**EDIT**

The above issue has been solved, thanks to **Phil** in the comments section. Turns out, I had saved the backend URL (notes-api-ttsn.onrender.com) in the Frontend `package.json` file through proxy - `"proxy": "https://notes-api-ttsn.onrender.com/"`. I removed the proxy and directly used the backend URL to fetch data from the front end, and at the backend I added a CORS setting to whitelist the frontend URL. Now I am able to log in/sign up.

**However**, now I am facing a new issue - whenever I log in/sign up the backend is supposed to store the session, and hence a cookie should be stored in the frontend to keep the user logged in. But after logging in, I cannot see the cookie anymore, and hence the notes API is failing with a `401 - User not authenticated` error (screenshot below).

[image: Notes API giving 401 error]
[image: Cookies not available]

Comment: _"call the APIs from Postman"_... what URLs are you trying? Because your web app is attempting a same-host request to `/api/users/login`

Comment: Hi Phil, one of the APIs I am calling from Postman is this - https://notes-api-ttsn.onrender.com/api/users/login. I have saved the backend URL (https://notes-api-ttsn.onrender.com) like this in the `package.json` file in Frontend - and it is working fine when I connect the local Frontend to deployed backend. 

`"proxy": "https://notes-api-ttsn.onrender.com/"`

Comment: you have somewhere wrongly formatted json/bson document, I vote that you're attempting to insert something incorrectly formatted during log in

Comment: The `proxy` only applies when running the webpack dev server. It has no effect on your production build

Comment: Hi Phil, thank you! I removed the proxy and directly used the backend URL to fetch data from the front end, and at the backend I added a CORS setting to whitelist the frontend URL. Now I am able to log in/sign up. However, now I am facing a new issue - whenever I log in/sign up the backend is supposed to store the session, and hence a cookie should be stored in the frontend to keep the user logged in. But after logging in, I cannot see the cookie anymore, and hence the notes API is failing with a `401 - User not authenticated` error (screenshot at the end of my question).

Answer (score 0):

follow this guide on how to properly set cookies: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies
It might be you're setting domain attribute while setting cookies and if that's the case, unless FE and BE domains match it won't get set.